# CSS type relationships

Tags: css, inheritance

Given CSS of

```
span.xml {color: #0000CC;}
span.ind0 {margin-left: 0em;}
```

And HTML of

```
<code>
<span class="ind0 xml">&lt;task /&gt;</span>
</code>
```

I get what I expect, as far as formatting. But now I want to add some internal spans, for more complex XML examples. Sp, with additional CSS of

```
span.xml.-text {color: #000000; font-weight: bold;}
```

And HTML of

```
<span class="ind0 xml">&lt;task&gt<span class="-text">TEXT</span>&lt;/task&gt;</span>
```

I expected the TEXT to be bold and back. Assuming that since the inner span is part of the outer span, and both the ind0 and xml styles are applied, the inner span would be of type xml AND ind1, and so that CSS would apply. Not so. Seems the outer span is of type span.ind0.xml, and that means the -text style doesn't get applied.

If I change the CSS to

```
span.xml-text {color: #000000; font-weight: bold;}
```

and the HTML to

```
<span class="ind0 xml">&lt;task&gt<span class="xml-text">TEXT</span>&lt;/task&gt;</span>
```

it works. But with lots of inner spans needed to properly color the various bits and pieces of complex XML, those extra characters do start getting in the way, which I was trying to avoid. But I am also trying to make my CSS more robust and extensible, since right now it is a mess. I have [this](https://css-tricks.com/abem-useful-adaptation-bem/) as a reference, which got me started on the -modifier convention. But I am obviously not understanding the subtleties.
So, is it even possible to have an outer span that takes two types, and then an inner span that can only be applied when one of those out types is applied? Or is it better to have those inner span types not be tied to the outer span type?

Comment: It seems you are looking for a child or even direct child `>` selector?

Comment: @ jbutler483 You would be correct. With that Selector concept to go search on I have `span.xml > span.-text {color: #000000; font-weight: bold;}` and that works as expected!

Comment: CSS is not OOP. Although child elements can inherit certain property values (esp. font settings), but this is more like hierarchal copying than OOP. I usually think of CSS selectors as 'if-statements'. BEM adds human readable logic, not OOP. Use the term 'copy' instead of 'inherit' and a lot of things become much more clear.